# Weak derivatives in $L^2$ are derivatives in norm(!)

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

I noticed something that strikes me as very curious regarding "weak derivatives" in $L^2$. The proof is so simple that the result is really just an "observation". But it's relevant to the definition of Sobolev spaces, so I'm wondering why I've never seen it. Of course I know nothing about Sobolev spaces, hence the **question**: *is* the result below actually out there somewhere?

$\newcommand\D{\mathcal D}$

If $f$ is a function on the line and $h\in\Bbb R$ define $$\tau_hf(t)=f(t+h).$$ Here on MSE we see people write $u(t+h)$ for distributions $u$, which is irritating; of course the right way to define a translate of $u\in\D'$ is $$\langle\tau_hu,\phi\rangle=\langle u,\tau_{-h}\phi\rangle\quad(\phi\in\D(\Bbb R)).$$

For $h\ne0$ define $$\Delta_hf=\frac{\tau_hf-f}{h},$$and similarly for $u$.

If $u\in \D'$ write $D_wu$ for the distribution-wise derivative. If $f,g\in L^2$ say $g=D_{L^2}f$ if $$||g-\Delta_hf||_2\to0\quad(h\to0).$$

> > **Easy Lemma.** If $u\in\D'$ then $\Delta_hu\to D_wu$ in $\D'$ as $h\to0$.

I believe this is just an exercise in Rudin *Functional Analysis*.

**Proof.** If $u\in\D'$ the definition of $\tau_hu$ shows that $$\langle\Delta_hu,\phi\rangle=-\langle u,\Delta_{-h}\phi\rangle,$$and
it's easy to show that $\Delta_{-h}\phi\to\phi'$ in $\D$ as $h\to0$.

> > **Curious Fact.** Suppose $f,g\in L^2(\Bbb R)$. Then $g=D_wf$ if and only if $g=D_{L^2}f$.

Strikes me as very curious; given $f,g\in L^2$ we have $\Delta_hf\to g$ in $\D'$ if and only if $\Delta_hf\to g$ in norm.

But regardless it really is just an "observation", in that the proof is sort of evident: It doesn't take a great deal of wit to conjecture that the Fourier transform might be useful, and when you look at the Fourier transform the proof just falls out. For newbies:

**Proof of the Curious Fact.** One direction is trivial from the Easy Lemma: If $g=D_{L^2}f$ then $\Delta_hf\to g$ in norm; hence $\Delta_hf\to g$ in $\D'$, so $g=D_wf$.

Suppose then that $g=D_wf$. Then of course $$\hat g(\xi)=i\xi\hat f(\xi),$$so in particular $$\int|\xi|^2|\hat f(\xi)|^2\,d\xi<\infty.$$
Now $$||g-\Delta_hf||_2^2=\int\left|i\xi-\frac{e^{ih\xi}-1}{h}\right|^2|\hat f(\xi)|^2\,d\xi\to 0\quad(h\to0)$$by dominated convergence (for the "dominated" recall that $|1-e^{it}|\le|t|$ for $t\in\Bbb R$).

(Similarly, Fatou's lemma shows that

> > Suppose $f\in L^2(\Bbb R)$. Then $D_wf\in L^2$ if and only if $||\Delta_hf||_2$ is bounded.)

Comment: Here is a different proof: you have $\| \Delta_h f\|_2 \le \|D_wf\|_2$ and $\Delta_h f \rightharpoonup D_w f$ in $L^2$. This implies convergence in norm.

Comment: @gerw Fine. How do you show $||\Delta_hf||_2\le||D_wf||_2$? (If you use the Fourier transform then this strikes me as not all that different; once you know the Fourier transform of $\Delta_hf$ it's obvious...)

Comment: Its basically Hölders inequality: https://books.google.de/books?id=eoiGTf4cmhwC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168

Comment: @gerw Curiously, google is  willing to show me p.168 and 170 bit not 169. But I can guess at the proof from p168: prove it for smoothh $u$ and then take a limit. Imo the proof above is simpler (if we include for example the proof that $C^\infty$ is dense in the "other" proof). Of course (i) the other proof works in domains other than $\Bbb R^d$, so it's _going_ to be harder, and (ii) this does show that the result is at least implicit in that book, answering my question somewhat.